# Firebase, getting an object after a search

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Hello  My goal is to test if an employee exists with the  $scope.CodeBarre value, into my FIREBASE database, then, the program will open a door, if $CodeBarre exists. The $CodeBarre var comes from a USB barcode Scan, that will scan the employe CardId...

This is my actual code :

```
  /* TEST DU CODE BARRE EN LIGNE */
 $scope.CodeBarre="GA13081982";
function testerLeCodebarre() {

    var ref = new Firebase('https://blinding-heat-8502.firebaseio.com/employes').orderByChild("identifiant").equalTo($scope.CodeBarre);
    $scope.employe = $firebaseArray(ref);

    console.log($scope.employe);
}
```

I'm getting the object in an array who $scope.employe that looks like this  :

[image: picture of the result into firebug]

I'm getting well the right employee but it's impossible to get it working into the angularJs view after, i simply can't get the name of the employe for exemple by typing  $scope.employe[0].nom

Note : if the employee is not found, then the returned array by firebase is not empty, but i simply can't find the employee object....

I've also tried with $firebaseObject but i can't get a regular AngularJs object .

Please could you help thank you

This is how my template looks like :

```
<div class="row">
        Bienvenue, {{employe.prenom}} {{employe.nom}}
</div>
```

2. Trying with $firebaseObject:

When i type this, trying to get an object instead of an array, it finds the employee well, but the problem is I can't access to it into my template, because I don't know the $ID by advance(this $ID is generated by Firebase) :

```
/* TEST DU CODE BARRE EN LIGNE */
```

function testerLeCodebarre() {

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://blinding-heat-8502.firebaseio.com/employes').orderByChild("identifiant").equalTo($scope.CodeBarre);
$scope.employe = $firebaseObject(ref);
console.log($scope.employe);
```

}

This is what i get into Firebug :

[Firebug when getting one object][2]

My wish would be simply to populate $scope.employe with the object who's got the $id -KIcVJh9sdVSWMamGaA3 that i'm getting from firebase, but i really don't know how to do it.

EDIT: So it works well with this :

```
    var ref = new Firebase('https://blinding-heat-8502.firebaseio.com/employes').orderByChild("identifiant").equalTo($scope.CodeBarre).once("value", function(snapshot) {
   var data = snapshot.val(); 
   if (data){
       console.log(data);

     //employee exists
     $scope.employe = data;
     console.log($scope.employe);
   }
```

But $scope.employe = data doesn't work in my template  :

```
<div class="row">
        Bienvenue, {{employe.prenom}} {{employe.nom}}
</div>
```

I still can't access the object, plus considering that i dont know the $id by advance :

[Object returned by firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa48e.jpg)

I've tried to type in my controller **data.nom** or **data.age** but gets undefined.
I've also tried $scope.employe = data.nom; but get undefined

Comment: What happens if you simply do: `{{ employe.age }}` in template? Using the `firebaseObject()` is fine, since you aim at retrieving only a single item. Then, if you retrieve an object, you don't have to use indexes on the item to get the items. Simply do `{{ employe.age }} {{ employe.addrese }}` etc.

Comment: Hello, Ok i have to try this now, and let you know .

Comment: will this  `$scope.CodeBarre` be unique?

Comment: Hem no, it comes from a USB barecode scanner, it's different each times hi hi.

Comment: @JojoBebert Did my suggestion work?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help rexford, yes it's now working with your syntax and the  adolfosrs gentle answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you will be always retrieving one employee so there is no need for using `$firebaseArray` in your case. Simply go with:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://blinding-heat-8502.firebaseio.com/employes').orderByChild("identifiant").equalTo($scope.CodeBarre).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
   var data = snapshot.val(); 
   if (data){
     //employee exists
     $scope.employe = data;
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I will try this and let you know, I dont know how to express my gratitude

Comment: It works very well and return an object name with the $id, unfortunatly, $scope.employe = data doesn't return data, i'm posting a picture

Comment: @JojoBebert my bad. just edited the code. try again using `child_added`.

Comment: This won't work well due to Firebase and `$digest` async nature. I would recommend using `$firebaseObject()`

Comment: Hey @DavidEast thanks for the info. Could you elaborate a little more on this or point me out any documentation?

Comment: Thank you a lot it works perfectly now ! You're really talented, i wish i could help in the future who knows ! Have a nice day, case closed, hi hi ! Firebase is a great technology !

Comment: @adolfosrs Angular works off the `$digest` loop to keep the model and view in sync. When they get out of sync Angular runs the loop. Async actions from external libraries won't trigger this loop. That's why we built AngularFire.

Comment: SOrry but maybe you could have Any idea on how to get the $id of $scope.employe because it's not present, i'm searching since 2 hours but can't find a way to find it.

Comment: @JojoBebert inside the `.on('child_added'` you can go with `snapshot.getKey()` or `snapshot.key`.